# getting multiple definition error when compiling source code

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I have a simple c++ app:

**node.h:**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace::std;

class Node
{
private:
    int data;
    Node *next;

public:
    Node(int nodeData,Node *nextNode);
};
```

**node.cpp:**

```
#include "node.h"


Node::Node(int nodeData, Node *nextNode) {
    data = nodeData;
    next = nextNode;
}
```

**linked_list.h**

```
#include "node.h"

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int size;
public:
    LinkedList();
    int getSize();
};
```

**linked_list.cpp:**

```
#include "linked_list.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    size = 0;
}

int LinkedList::getSize() {
    return size;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"
#include "linked_list.h"

using namespace ::std;

int main()
{
    cout << "This is main!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I am on linux, inside the projcet's directory, I open a terminal there and try to compile them by this command:

```
g++ *.cpp *.h -o app
```

but I get this error:

```
In file included from linked_list.h:1:0,
                 from main.cpp:3:
node.h:1:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Node’
 class Node
       ^~~~
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
node.h:1:7: note: previous definition of ‘class Node’
 class Node
       ^~~~
```

I looked at some posts here on stackoverlfow but had no luck in solving my problem. I am new to c++, I know that the compiler thinks I am redefining class `Node` somewhere, but where is this somewhere so I can remove the definition?

Comment: Put `#pragma once` at the beginning of every header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `linked_list.h` includes `node.h`, so the compiler will see the definition in `node.h` twice while compiling `main.cpp`.

To avoid this problem, you should add "include guard" to your header files.
It should be like this:

**node.h**:

```
#ifndef NODE_H_GUARD // add this
#define NODE_H_GUARD // add this

#include<iostream>

using namespace::std;

class Node
{
private:
    int data;
    Node *next;

public:
    Node(int nodeData,Node *nextNode);
};

#endif // add this
```

The macro name to define and check should be different for each headers.

Another way to avoid this problem is to adding `#pragma once` as the first lines of your headers if your compiler supports this.

Comment: the `#ifndef` method worked without warnings, the `pragma` method worked but gave me warning : `node.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
 #pragma once
         ^~~~` is this ok?

Comment: You shouldn't include `*.h` in your compiling command line because `*.h` files are for being included from `*.cpp` files and not for compiled directly.